# change terminal run directory using TK

Tags: unix, tcl

While I'm working, I need to change directories frequently. So, I write a small code like this, but it is not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/wish
button .exit -text exit -command {exit}
pack .exit -padx 20 -pady 10

button .dir1 -text e1_b_r1_IcPlace -command {exec cd ..}
pack .dir1 -padx 20 -pady 10
```

The above code showing an error:

> couldn't execute "cd": no such file or directory

Comment: `cd` *is* a command, you don't need any `exec` before it.

Comment: You cannot do what you are trying to do: a child process cannot alter the environment of the parent process. The `cd` command is built into the shell, and your wish program cannot alter the shell that spawned it. If you write a Tcl program that combines Tk and Expect, you can spawn a shell and control it with a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

The `exec` command starts new processes executing system commands or running script files. You don't need it to invoke the `cd` command, just the command itself:

```
button .dir1 -text e1_b_r1_IcPlace -command {cd ..}
```

If you want to specify a directory *at the time the button is created* you can use something like this:

```
button .dir1 -text e1_b_r1_IcPlace -command [list cd $dir]
```

If you want the directory to be specified at the time that the button is invoked, this is one way to do it:

```
entry .dir1ent -textvariable dir
button .dir1 -text e1_b_r1_IcPlace -command {cd $dir}
```

The braces keep the variable `dir` from being substituted until the button is invoked, at which point `cd` is invoked with the current text of the entry widget as argument.

**Update:** as glenn jackman notes, this code will only affect its own process and cannot in this form be used as a "remote control" for a regular shell. However, if you use `tkcon` as a command shell and launch this code from it, the button *will* change the working directory in the shell.

Documentation: [button](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/button.htm), [cd](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/cd.htm), [entry](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/entry.htm), [exec](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm)